# How is the percentile for each tag in Developer Story calculated?

Tags: discussion

I see the percentile in Developer Story.

Is it calculated based on the `total updvotes minus the downvotes` or **the total reputation**?

For me suppose my score for **Java** is **136**, *but there are lot of answers where the answer is accepted but not upvoted, and also lot of answers whose score is 0 because of one upvote and one downvote, but have gained 8 reputations for that.*

Comment: Meh, just one upvote puts you in the 50 percentile at SO and makes you a rock-star.  With some luck they won't look at your profile and see what happened on Nov 5th or Aug 21st, etc.  I would, seen it all, the white-board test culls the BS-ers anyway.  Just a waste of my time trying to find people to hire, shame on SO for not making it easier.  At all.